# Drawing Curves/Bezier Lines with ESRI WPF Runtime

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, wpf, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I'm looking for some pointers on how to draw a curved line or bezier line in WPF runtime. The WPF runtime sample application has a drawing mode for straight line, polyline, and freehand. However, no curve or bezier.

Here is **[an example in Silverlight](http://broux.dominique.free.fr/Silverlight/InteractiveDrawing/InteractiveDrawing.html)**, so it seems like it should be possible in WPF as well.  ...

Here is **[the page describing the app as well as source code download](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1e432da7e74f4402bd43a5863167022d)**:  ...

I haven't had a chance to do a deep dive into the source code yet. It looks somewhat complicated at first glance.

P.S. I do have an ArcObjects engine runtime license available as part of my solution as well - just in case a hybrid solution would work.